# html / iphone - getting a form alert when attempting to refresh the page

Tags: iphone, html, forms

I'm building a site which has a form but for some reason, even if a user doesn't enter info into the form (even if the form hasn't been presented yet - it starts out hidden) - if I refresh the page, iOS gives me a browser alert stating:

are you sure you want to submit this form again?

Any idea why this happens or how to suppress that?

This is my form code:

```
<div id="vehicle_form">
    <form method="post" name="emailForm">
    <input class="dField" id="dfEmail" type="email" name="email" value="Email"/><br/>
    <input class="dField" id="dfName" type="text" name="firstname" value="First Name"/><br/>
    <input class="dField" id="dfLast" type="text" name="lastname" value="Last Name"/><br/>
    <input class="dField" id="dfZip" type="text" maxlength="5" name="zip" value="Zip Code"/><br/>
    <button id="dFormBack">Back</button><button type="submit" id="dSubmit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <div id="dErrors"></div>
</div>
```

I also have this javascript acting on the form fields:

```
$j('.dField').focus(function(){
    clearInput($j(this)[0]); //The [0] seems to be necessary to retrieve the element at the DOM object level
}).blur(function(){
    restoreInput($j(this)[0]);
});
```

as well as some other form related javascript.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but try this:

```
<form method="post" name="emailForm">
<input type="text" name="email" value="Email" size="30" onfocus="value=''"><br>
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="First Name" size="30" onfocus="value=''"><br>
<input type="text" name="lastname" value="Last Name" size="30" onfocus="value=''"><br>
<input type="text" name="zipcode" value="Zip Code" size="30" onfocus="value=''"><br>
<button id="dFormBack">Back</button><button type="submit" id="dSubmit">Submit</button>
</form>
```